# Añadir datos a un objeto form dinámico

Tags: javascript

Tengo dos objetos creados con javascript que son: **form** y **FormData**. La información de `FormData` quiero pasarla al `form` para luego hacer `form.submit()`.

Código que llevo:

```
var data = new FormData();
var form = document.createElement("form");

/* AGREGAR DATOS */
data.append(...);
data.append(...);
...

// ¿ form.append(data); ?

document.body.appendChild(form);
form.submit();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes enviar directamente el FormData mediante un objeto XMLHttpRequest:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
xhr.open("POST", form.action, false)
xhr.send(data)
```

Comment: Lo del form.submit(); es para abrir la petición en otra ventana. (target:_blank)